# Is this probability exercise solvable?

Tags: probability

I've been working in a somewhat strange probability problem, which appears to be a variation on a well known exercise which is easily sovable though prob laws. The problem says as follows:

> A group of 2500 have been polled about what theu have seen on TV last night. 2100 of them saw a movie; 1500 saw a debate; 350 of them saw both the movie and the debate. Find a) Probabilty of a random person having seen either the movie or the debate; b) Probability of a person having seen the movie, knowing she saw the debate

As soon as I try to set up a Venn diagram, I get that 2100-350 people have only seen the movie, and 1500-350 people have only seen the debate. However, (2100-350)+(1500-350) is more than 2500. I also tryied to set up a table, and I got:

[image]

Which also yields and absurd sum.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some sort of mistake in the problem?
Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you assuming that no one was doing something else entirely, so neither watching TV nor the debate?

Comment: $1150+0=1150$ rather than $0$.  But that is not the real difficulty here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine and the problem is not correct.  You don't know that there are $0$ people who saw neither show.  In fact if $-750$ people saw neither it all works out.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a mistake in the problem.

If you complete the table:

```
         | Debate | No Debate | SUM
---------+--------+-----------+-----
Movie    | 350    | 1750      | 2100
No Movie | 1150   | -750      |  400
SUM      | 1500   | 1000      | 2500
```

you would get $(-750)$ people who did not watch the movie and did not watch the debate.

The total number of people should be *at least* $3250$ instead of $2500$ for the problem to make sense.